# Grails 2.4 won't read config file from /opt

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

**Please note:** Although I'm using the [Grails Shiro plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/shiro) I believe this to be a core Grails problem, having nothing to do with the plugin whatsoever.

---

Mac (Yosemtie) and Grails 2.4.5 here. Here's the top 2 lines from my `Config.groovy`:

```
String configFileAbsPath = System.getProperty('configFileAbsPath')
grails.config.locations = [ "file:${configFileAbsPath}" ]
```

So to run locally I do something like:

```
grails -DconfigFileAbsPath=/Users/myuser/tmp/myapp.properties run-app
```

When I run this exact invocation, my app starts up and behaves just fine.

However, in non-local environments I want my config file to live under `/opt/myapp/myapp.properties`. So on my local machine I create a `/opt/myapp` directory, and then ran `chmod -R 777 /opt/myapp`. I then copy `myapp.properties` to it and run:

```
grails -DconfigFileAbsPath=/opt/myapp/myapp.properties run-app
```

This produces the following stack trace:

```
| Error Error generating web.xml file (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: shiro for class: java.lang.String
    at ShiroGrailsPlugin$_closure4_closure30_closure34.doCall(ShiroGrailsPlugin.groovy:248)
    at ShiroGrailsPlugin$_closure4_closure30_closure34.doCall(ShiroGrailsPlugin.groovy)
    at ShiroGrailsPlugin$_closure4_closure30.doCall(ShiroGrailsPlugin.groovy:243)
    at ShiroGrailsPlugin$_closure4_closure30.doCall(ShiroGrailsPlugin.groovy)
    at ShiroGrailsPlugin$_closure4.doCall(ShiroGrailsPlugin.groovy:242)
```

**I seriously doubt that the location of an external config file, or the file permissions set on the config file (or its parent dir) would break the Grails Shiro plugin.** I think this is just a misleading Grails/Groovy exception. Most likely some kind of security exception is causing something to not load/populate correctly (and fail silently), and then when Grails Shiro kicks in during `run-app`, its missing something that should be there and is causing `run-app` to die.

Any ideas as to what is going on, or what the fix is?

---

**Update**: Running `grails clean`, `grails clean-all` and/or `grails refresh-dependencies` prior to invoking `grails run-app` do not help/solve this error either.

Comment: As the user that is invoking grails run app can it cat the file on that location? My question relates to chown not chmod. Try chown -r user:user to path of folder containing config. I posted an alternative of loading external configuration on another similar post a week ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally prefer to have .groovy file for external config rather than .properties because I can write printlns into it to check whether the file is loaded or not.